# DebugKit in cakephp 3.x do not show DebugKit Toolbar

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

`DebugKit` Toolbar do not show at the top-right of my `localhost/thegioididong page`.

[image]

Comment: you have to set debug=true

Comment: [app.php img link](https://i.imgur.com/4HO0c7L.png) check it please. I'm not sure it true that way. I downloaded Cakephp 3.5.14 on [github_cakephp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags) and every thing was there.

Comment: Instead of uploading images why don't you just copy/paste the code? Anyway: just set debug=true in app.php

Comment: @arilia I'm sorry, next time i'll post it as `code`. I'm stucking with these things, coding was fine (i checked, everything as in `https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit`) but DebugKit toolbar do not show itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved it and I will post an answer for this post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED! I do these thing:

1: check the `debug` status at the top of `config\app.php`.

```
`'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),`
```

2: add to the end of `config\bootstrap.php` these codes:

```
`if (Configure::read('debug')) {
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}`
```

3: create `debug_kit` table in mysql database - leave it empty database (localhost/phpmyadmin - in my case), then add:

```
'debug_kit' => [
'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
'persistent' => false,
'host' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'root1234',
'database' => 'debug_kit', //leave it empty - without tables
'encoding' => 'utf8',
'timezone' => 'UTC',
'flags' => [],
'cacheMetadata' => true,
'log' => false,
'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
],
```

into `config\app.php` following this structure:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        //default database config here
    ],
    'debug_kit' => [
        //debug_kit database config as above
    ],

    'test' => [
        //test database config here
    ],
],
```

Thanks a lot. I'm sory for my English!

Comment: Excellent info. I didn't place the debug_kit info in the right place in app.php file, this helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
bin/cake plugin assets symlink
```

to load debugkit assets.

Comment: I SOLVED it and then I POSTED an answer for my question! remove your answer please!

Comment: Most time problem like this is when app not loading plugin asset.

Comment: @Mr.D I had the exact same probolem. I solved it by following your answer _and_ but running this line of code. I think it is a useful contribution. EDIT: This was using CakePHP 3.6.6

Comment: Main reason why debugkit is not showing it´s because not loading asset files or php sqlite extension is not installed! Use solution with change debug_kit db only if you can´t install/use sqlite extension.

Answer (score 2):

in my case cake 3.5  this lines of code work

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Configure::write('DebugKit', ['forceEnable' => true]);
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```

add this line at the end of bootstrap.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this in your bootstrap.php file?

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```

Comment: [Bootstrap.php image](https://i.imgur.com/9jRG14K.png) , I downloaded Cakephp 3.5.14 on [github_cakephp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags) and everything was there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved it and I will post an answer for this post!

Answer (score 1):

For CakePHP 3.x:

1. Check if "debug" is set to true. You may add `debug('test');` somewhere in your app and check if you see the word "test" in your website's code at the beginning.
2. Check that debugkit plugin is loaded by adding `debug(Plugin::loaded('DebugKit'));` at the end of **bootstrap.php**. This should echo "true".
3. <s>Add `Configure::write('DebugKit', ['forceEnable' => true]);` before you load DebugKit.</s>
   Add your development TLD to the "safeTld" property. (thanks @mark)

```php
     // Allow e.g. http://foo.bar.dev or http://my-shop.local domains locally
     Configure::write('DebugKit.safeTld', ['dev', 'local', 'example']);
```

4. Copy or symlink asset plugins running `bin/cake plugin assets symlink (use copy on windows)`
    [Docs here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/deployment.html#symlink-assets).
5. Make sure you have sqlite extension installed. If you're using Laragon, enable Sqlite extensions in Menu > PHP > Extensions (this is what fixed my issue).

Comment: Do not use forceEnable, use the documented whitelist for TDLs.

Comment: See this url for whitelist details: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html#configuration

Comment: @mark I understand the security concerns but `Configure::write('DebugKit.safeTld', ['dev.example.com']);` didn't fix it for me when navigating to `dev.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

enabled sqlite, for linux mint

```
nano /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

uncomment

```
extension=sqlite3
```

restart apache

```
 service service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Also needed in his case: whitelist of TLD added, as he doesn't use the recommended defaults (`.local` etc).

Comment: In linux system you can use command    
"sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3"